# Solving ODE $\frac{(1-2y)y'}{y-y^2}=(x+4)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
$$\frac{(1-2y)y'}{y-y^2}=(x+4)^3.$$

The answer is supposed to be $$\ln\Bigl(y(1-y)\Bigr)=\frac{(x+4)^4}{4}+C.$$

However, I'm not sure how to get to that answer.

I can easily see how to get the right side of the answer, I know that's the integral of $(x+4)^3$.  I expanded the left side to get

$$\frac{y'-2yy'}{y-y^2}.$$

I'm assuming I have to do the integral of that somewhere to get $\ln$, but this is where I got stuck.  How do I do the rest of the problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1-2 y=(y-y^2)'$.  Then the LHS is of the form $f'(y)/f(y)$ which is equivalent to $(d/dy) \log{f(y)}$ where $f(y)=y-y^2$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's all I had to do?  I feel a little silly now.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I tried to redo the problem and I don't understand why $f'(y)/f(y)$ is equal to $(d/dy)logf(y)$.  Also, how am I supposed to use $(d/dy)logf(y)$ to solve the problem?  Sorry, it's just not clicking for me.

Comment: Recall the chain rule and that $(d/dz) \log{z} = 1/z$.  Note aso that the LHS becomes an exact integral: $$\int \frac{d}{dy} \log{f(y)} y' dx = \int \frac{d}{dy} \log{f(y)} dy =  \log{f(y)} + C$$

Comment: Ok, that looks like it makes sense!  I will try to redo the problem on my own later and see if I can get to the solution.  Thank you!